# ターミナルで入れ子のコマンドが実行できません

Tags: iterm

```
gnome-terminal -e ping -c 2 192.168.1.1
```

というコマンドですが、gnome-terminal -eの中にping -c 2 192.168.1.1という入れ子状になったコマンドでターミナルで実行してみたところ

> 引数を解析できませんでした: -c は不明なオプションです

となってしまい実行できません

```
gnome-terminal -e ping 192.168.1.1
```

とすると実行はできるのですがpingの方にもオプションがほしいですどのようにしたら実行できますか

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gnome-terminal -e 'ping -c 2 192.168.1.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

別解として、gnome-terminal には`-x` オプションが用意されています。

> gnome-terminal(1)
>
> -x, --execute
> 　　Execute **the remainder of the command line** inside the terminal.

ですので、

```
$ gnome-terminal -x ping -c 2 192.168.1.1
```

とすることもできます。

Answer (score 3):

では更に別解を。

```
% cat bin/ping-192
#!/bin/sh
exec ping -c 2 192.168.1.1
% gnome-terminal -e bin/ping-192
```

単純に ping だけでは済まなくなって、もっと複雑なことをしたくなった時にでもどうぞ。